# Change default decimal numbers parsing behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I am getting the following response of a web service call:

```
response = "{\"price\":39.74000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875}"
```

Then I'm parsing it:

```
json = JSON.parse(response, {:symboize_names: true})
```

The result is:

```
json = {price: 39.74}
```

Then I tried from Rails console to check if it is happening because of `JSON` library, but simply I got the following result:

```
>> data = {:price => 39.74000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875}
{:price=>39.74}
```

So it's default behavior in Rails and I need to change it (*on application level*) to always parse decimal numbers as `BigDecimal` instead of `float`.

**Ruby = 2.3.0**

**Rails = 4.2.4**

Can anybody help?

Comment: Better way for critical numeric data handling is store them as `decimal` type at database level.

Comment: I don't need to save it to db and I'm not dealing with `ActiveRecord` in my case.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. Gives TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String.

Comment: @sawa Rails version = 4.2.4 & Ruby version = 2.3.0

Comment: That is irrelevant.

Comment: @sawa Actually I'm unable to reproduce what you've got 'TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String'

Comment: It is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @sawa response body is possibly a string, and Moamen passing this one to JSON.parse. You are passing hash to JSON.parse so it raises TypeError.

Comment: @MoamenNaanou can you please double check the response line you've posted. You've posted ruby hash, not json

Comment: @NikitaMisharin and sawa thanks you are correct, In my question I'm passing hash (my mistake), that was only to simplify my question, now it is updated to original response.

Comment: @sawa now I know why I was unable to reproduce your error :)

Comment: @marmeladze Exactly. I am passing exactly what the OP wrote, and reporting that result.

Comment: @sawa but the issue of decimal precision is not solved

Comment: Of course not. The code you claiming to be using to parse it is not even ruby code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a hack really, but I couldn't find any better

```
response = "{\"price\":39.74000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875}"
transformed_response = response.gsub(/\d+\.\d+/, '"\&"')
hash = JSON.parse(transformed_response , symboize_names: true})
```

The resulting `hash` will be

```
{ price: "39.74000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875" }
```

With which you can do something like this

```
hash.tap { |hash| hash[:price] = BigDecimal.new(hash[:price]) }
```

Comment: Your answer is very close as a temporary fix, thanks, but the result number after gsub is different number.

Comment: @MoamenNaanou Sorry, what you mean different number?

Comment: I'm shocked now, first time I implement your fix, I got `"{\"price\":\"47.9390070000\"}"` as a value of `transformed_response` but now again I did exactly the same and I got `"{\"price\":\"39.74000000000000198951966012828052043914794921875\"}"` so thanks a lot

Comment: @MoamenNaanou I know why it didn't work the first time. I've updated the answer, please use the updated version